# How to fetch limited rows by grouping item in one table in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, limit

I have a table named "news_box".
That has 3 field. "channel_id", "news_id", "read"

channel_id and news_id together are primary key.

sample of data can this:

```
channel_id | news_id | read
-----------|---------|-----
1          | 1       | 0
1          | 2       | 0
2          | 3       | 0
3          | 4       | 0
2          | 5       | 0
3          | 6       | 0
3          | 7       | 0
3          | 8       | 0
3          | 9       | 0
1          | 10      | 0
1          | 11      | 0
1          | 12      | 0
2          | 13      | 0
3          | 14      | 0
2          | 15      | 0
3          | 16      | 0
3          | 17      | 0
3          | 18      | 0
3          | 19      | 0
1          | 20      | 0
```

now i want to get 3 row of "news_id" per each "channel_id".
"news_id" and "channel_id" join with self table.

sample of result can this:

```
channel_id | news_id | read
-----------|---------|-----
1          | 1       | 0
1          | 2       | 0
2          | 3       | 0
3          | 4       | 0
2          | 5       | 0
3          | 6       | 0
3          | 7       | 0
1          | 10      | 0
2          | 13      | 0
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
set @num := 0, @group := 0;

select channel_id, `news_id`, `read`
from 
(
   select channel_id, `news_id`, `read`,
      @num := if(@group = `channel_id`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @group := `channel_id` as dummy
  from news_box
  order by `channel_id`
) as x where x.row_number <= 3;
```